# Unable to fetch data from Salesforce from Java using R.

Tags: java, r, salesforce

I am running SAQL query using R on java console to bypass the wsdl connectivity.
I am able to connect, but unable to retrieve data. below is the code.

```
caller.addRCode("username <- \"xxxxx@xxxxxx.com\"");
caller.addRCode("password <- \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"");
caller.addRCode("instanceURL <- \"https://ap2.salesforce.com/\"");
caller.addRCode("apiVersion <- \"38.0\"");          
caller.addRCode("(session<-rforcecom.login(username, password, instanceURL, apiVersion))");
caller.addRCode("soqlQuery <- \"SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 10\"");
caller.addRCode("outc <- rforcecom.query(session, soqlQuery)");

caller.runAndReturnResult("outc");
String[] outcm = caller.getParser().getAsStringArray("outc");
for (int i=0;i<10; i++)
System.out.println("outcm[i]");`
```

The last 4 lines giving the following error.

rcaller.exception.RCallerParseException: Can not parse the R output: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

Please let me know how to get this sorted out. I am expecting some alphanumeric string as output.

Thanks,
Souvik

Answer (score 0):

Output of `rforcecom.query(session, soqlQuery)` will be an array of array of string. I think you will find following link useful: https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-salesforce/ and https://hiratake55.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/rforcecom/